# Use EMCLI to update OEM Oracle Home Path

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

Is is possible to use the [Enterprise Manager Command Line Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/em.121/e17786/concepts.htm#sthref9) (EMCLI) to change the Oracle Home Path?

We recently upgraded many databases, listeners, and ASMs, and I'd like to automate this process:

1. Select the target
2. Go to Target Setup --> Monitoring Configuration
3. Change "Oracle Home Path", click Next, click Submit.

I looked through the EMCLI [Verb Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/em.121/e17786/cli_verb_ref.htm#BABHCIIG) and could not find a way to do this.

Comment: I have this book : http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-Enterprise-Manager-Command-Line-Interface/dp/1484202392/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1425238986&sr=8-1&keywords=oracle+enterprise+manager+12c+command-line+interface, and when I browse through the code-examples I can see they are calling emcli.set_target_property_value to do what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DB target name as seen in EM is `ORCL11.WORLD` and you want to set it's Monitoring Configuration's Oracle Home to `/oracle/product/11.2.0.4`, the syntax would be the following:

```
emcli modify_target -type='oracle_database' -name='ORCL11.WORLD' -properties='OracleHome:/oracle/product/11.2.0.4'
```

Probably would be similar approach for Listeners, ASM, etc.

Version note: This worked for me on EM 12cR4.

Comment: On Windows this command only worked with double quotes instead of single quotes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> emcli modify_target -type='oracle_listener' -name='LISTENER_mx0102.orademo.com' -properties='Machine:mx0102.orademo.com';
>   Target "LISTENER_m0102.orademo.com:oracle_listener" modified successfully